# Querying a many-to-many table by grouping

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, linq

I have a many-to-many relationship table that I am trying to do a lookup on like a dictionary.

### Item

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          Id         |       Name       |      Desc       |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          1          |       One        |   First Item    |
|          2          |       Two        |   Second Item   |
|          3          |       Three      |   Third Item    |
|          4          |       Four       |   Fourth Item   |
|          5          |       Five       |   Fifth Item    |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
```

### Collection

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Id         |       Name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          | First Collection |
|          2          | Second Collecton |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

### Inventory

```
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|     CollectionId    |       ItemId     |    Amount    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|          1          |         1        |       14     |
|          1          |         2        |       4      |
|          1          |         5        |       4      |
|          2          |         1        |       2      |
|          2          |         5        |       9      |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
```

I am trying to design a query to get all CollectionIds where some the CollectionId has a relation to every ItemId in some input set?

It am struggling to find words to describe my intention, but the pseudo code would look like this

```
SearchFromIncludes(HashSet<Item> list)
{
  Dictionary<HashSet<Item>, ItemContainer> lookupTable = MakeTable();
  List<ItemContainer> matches = [];
  for (key in getKeys(lookupTable))
  {
     // if all items in the item list exist in the lookup key, add it for return
     if (AllItemsExist(key, list))
     {
       matches.Add(lookupTable.getValue(key));
     }
     return matches;
  }
}
```

So if `MakeTable` creates the relationship above as a dictionary

```
{
  [1, 2, 3]: 1,
  [1, 5]: 2
}
```

`SearchFromIncludes([1, 5])` would return

```
[1]
```

`SearchFromIncludes([1, 3, 5])` would return

```
[1, 2]
```

Is there a SQL strategy for querying information from a many-to-many table in this way, where you want to get an item from a relation where its related item match an input set exactly? I am thinking GROUP BY may be helpful here but I have not gotten it to work successfully

Ultimately I will be doing this with Entity Framework Core/LINQ, but I would also like to know how this would look as SQL

Comment: First of all, your sql table schema is not correct. Collection is the table in which both tables (Item & Inventory) Ids would be entered. Its essential for many to many relation.

Comment: I would try to count the number of matching inventory records with any of the item ids, then compare the count to the expected number of ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable itemTable = new DataTable();
            itemTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            itemTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            itemTable.Columns.Add("Desc", typeof(string));

            itemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "One", "First Item" });
            itemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Two", "Second Item" });
            itemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Three", "Third Item" });
            itemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Four", "Fourth Item" });
            itemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Five", "Fifth Item" });

            DataTable collectionTable = new DataTable();
            collectionTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            collectionTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            collectionTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "First Collection" });
            collectionTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Second Collection" });

            DataTable inventoryTable = new DataTable();
            inventoryTable.Columns.Add("CollectionId", typeof(int));
            inventoryTable.Columns.Add("ItemId", typeof(int));
            inventoryTable.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));

            inventoryTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 14 });
            inventoryTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 4 });
            inventoryTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 5, 4 });
            inventoryTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1, 2 });
            inventoryTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 5, 9 });

            Dictionary<int, List<object>> dict = (from inTable in inventoryTable.AsEnumerable()
                                            join cTable in collectionTable.AsEnumerable() on inTable.Field<int>("CollectionId") equals cTable.Field<int>("Id")
                                            join iTable in itemTable.AsEnumerable() on inTable.Field<int>("ItemId") equals iTable.Field<int>("Id")
                                            select new { inTable = inTable, cTable = cTable, iTable = iTable }
                                           ).ToList()
                                           .GroupBy(x => x.cTable.Field<int>("Id"), y => new  { itemTableRow = y.iTable, amount = y.inTable.Field<int>("Amount") })
                                           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList<object>());
        }
    }
}
```